# Nikon-F to Eyepiece

Tags: lens-adapter

I have some large focal length Nikon-F lenses. Attaching them to my camera I can use them as a spotting scope.

Are there any eyepieces I can attach them to directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there exists a Nikon Lens Scope Converter:

http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/lsc.htm

However, this item is no longer in production, so you need to find one second-hand. Read the description carefully, since it will not work with all lenses. It works with all pre-AI, AI, AIS, AF, AF-D, and AF-S lenses EXCEPT for the "G" lenses which lack aperture controls. "G" lenses automatically close to minimum aperture when removed from the camera and the lens scope converter has no way to open them up.

You can also make one yourself, as described here:

http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00HfRR